# Does a CNAME "hide" the domain you're CNAME'ing to?

Tags: dns, cloudflare, cname, a-records

Say domain `A.COM` has a CNAME for `www` which points to `B.COM`, and `B.COM` also has a `www` CNAME which points to `C.COM`, and `C.COM` has multiple A records/IP's.

Is there any way for someone snooping around to query `A.COM` and see that it's simply pointing to `B.COM`? Or is it impossible to get that information without having full access to the DNS zone manager (meaning all they would see are the final IP's that `C.COM` resolve to)?

EDIT: I'm using CloudFlare (A, B, & C), so I'm not sure if that changes the answer. It seems to me they all point to CloudFlare as A records and you can't pull out a CNAME?

Comment: You may be running into CloudFlare's CNAME Flattening if you created all of the CNAMES on the root of the zone. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a CNAME does not hide anything. You can run a `dig WWW.A.COM` and it will show you the CNAME pointer. That said, casual users browsing your website will never see or know that your website points to `C.COM`.

Example:

```
$ dig ak.nextag.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ak.nextag.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9813
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ak.nextag.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ak.nextag.com.      879 IN  CNAME   img.nextag.com.
img.nextag.com.     86379   IN  CNAME   img05.static-nextag.com.
img05.static-nextag.com. 7179   IN  CNAME   d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net.
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.195
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.200
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.186
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.218
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.251
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.132
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.42
d2lhs8hfggtuez.cloudfront.net. 39 IN    A   54.230.143.7

;; Query time: 106 msec
;; SERVER: 10.100.51.31#53(10.100.51.31)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul  8 01:18:44 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 254
```

Comment: When I do that it shows the IP that `C.COM` resolves to?

Comment: When I do `dig a.com` I get 2 rows back for 2 `A records` which point to 2 CloudFlare IP's (no CNAME anywhere in the output). I'm using OSX